# Printing an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, printing

Now I understand that you cant just use echo to print the contents of an array and you have to use foreach but for some reason this is not working. Any ideas?

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows as $key=>$row)
       {
        echo "My value at $key is $row";
       }
}
```

Output:

```
My value at 0 is ArrayMy value at 1 is ArrayMy value at 2 is Array
```

Comment: Your `$row` is another array, so you have a multidimensional array and you have to do another foreach()

Comment: What's wrong with `var_dump`?

Comment: If you did a dump of your array like Harnish said, then you would know it was a 2d array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you've fetched something from PDO using `fetchAll`.

This method returns an array of arrays (rows). The inner arrays have `column_name => value` elements. So for example if you retrieved the column 'firstName' and 'lastName', these values for the first record will be `$rows[0]['firstName']` and `$rows[0]['lastName']` respectivelly.

The proper way to do this would be:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
    foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
        echo "My $column value for row $key is $value\n";
    }
}
```

Protip: Watch the parentheses alignment, this doesn't matter for correctness but makes the code more readable :)

Comment: Thank you sir. I figured it would be a lot more similar to python.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a multi-dimensional array to me. Try [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump) or [`print_r`](http://php.net/print_r)

```
var_dump($rows);
print_r($rows);
```

Answer (score 1):

$row is another array which can not be converted directly to string. You can use this function to check array content.

```
function d($data)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    echo '</pre>';
}
d($stmt->fetchAll());
```

and better you do this (if you forgot to remove its calling doesn't harm your site)

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
function d($data)
{
    if(ENVIRONMENT == 'development')
    {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    echo '</pre>';
    }
}
d($stmt->fetchAll());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//<pre> tag will give you a well formatted version of var_dump  
echo "<pre>"; 
var_dump($rows);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to debug the content of `$row`:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($rows as $key=>$row)
{
    echo "First key: $key | ";

    foreach($row as $subkey => $subrow)
    {
        echo "Subkey: $subkey | Value: $subrow <br />";
    }

}
```

Addiotinally, it's important to use functions like [var_dump()](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), [print_r()](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) and [var_export()](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php), they will prevent a lot of problems for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
//@parram $data-array,$d-if true then die by default it is false
 //@author Your name

 function p($data,$d = false){

     echo "<pre>"; 
         print_r($data);
     echo "</pre>"; 

     if($d == TRUE){
        die();
     } 
} // END OF FUNCTION
```

Use this function every time whenver you need to string or array it will wroks just GREAT. 
There are 2 Patameters 
1.$data - It can be Array or String
2.$d - By Default it is FALSE but if you set to true then it will execute die() function

In your case you can write like this..

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($rows as $key=>$row) {
      p($rows);  // to use p function use above code for p() in your code   
}
```